# i want to print Korean(language) in (python-opencv)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

print korean error

[image]

```
if consecutive == 2 and res not in ['nothing']:
                    if res == 'space':
                        sequence += ' '
                    elif res == 'del':
                        sequence = sequence[:-1]
                    else:
                        cnt += 1
                        sequence += res
                        if cnt == 3:
                            sequence = sequence[:-3]
                            sequence += '안'
                            cnt = 0

                    consecutive = 0
            i += 1
            cv2.putText(img, '%s' % (res.upper()), (100,400), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 4, (255,255,255), 4)
            cv2.putText(img, '(score = %.5f)' % (float(score)), (100,450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255))
            mem = res
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,0,0), 2)
            cv2.imshow("img", img)
            img_sequence = np.zeros((200,1200,3), np.uint8)
            cv2.putText(img_sequence, '%s' % (sequence.upper()), (30,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255), 2)
            cv2.imshow('sequence', img_sequence)
```

//  It is not whole code. '안' is korean lauguage.  It`s working alpahbet but han-guel(korean language) is not working. what is problem?

Comment: '안' print '???' in cmd(window)

Comment: I just know 'cv::puttext' is not support korean language
how fix it?

Comment: unfortunately it is not putText doesn't supports only subset of ascii characters. you have to find your own way. https://github.com/msly/codemanage/tree/master/opencv may be helpful.